# Get rid of "reference to free variable" byte-compilation warnings

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm writing an emacs major mode, which uses buffer-local variables to store some state:

```lisp
(defun foo-mode ()
  "My nice major mode"
  (interactive)
  (kill-all-local-variables)
  (setq mode-name "foo")
  (setq major-mode 'foo-mode)
  (set (make-local-variable 'foo-state) "bar"))

(defun foo-change-state ()
  (setq foo-state "baz"))
```

This works very well and has the property that in any buffer not using my major mode, the `foo-state` variable is not bound (which is a good thing in my opinion, since it avoids cluttering the symbols table).

However, byte-compiling such a piece of code produces the following warning:

```
Warning: assignment to free variable `foo-state'
```

Using `defvar` gets rid of the warning, but has the side-effect that `foo-state` is now bound everywhere, which is undesirable in my opinion.

Is there a way to get rid of the warnings while still not binding the mode-specific variables in every buffer? Or am I mistaken when I think these variables should not be declared globally?

Comment: Well *that* was a particularly unhelpful answer-to-comment conversion by someone. To make the above readable again: `C-h i g (elisp) Warning Tips RET` is where the documentation which answers this question lives.

Comment: @phils Yes. I, for one, did like your answer. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I recommend you use `define-derived-mode`, as in `(define-derived-mode foo-mode nil "foo" "My nice major mode." (set (make-local-variable 'foo-state) "bar"))`.

Comment: Beware! The `Warning Tips` section in the Emacs Manual contains a blatant lie regarding `defvar`: "Such a definition has no effect except to tell the compiler not to warn about uses of the variable [...] in this file.". It most certainly can have more impact than just silencing the compiler: "[it] also declares the variable as "special", so that it is always dynamically bound even if ‘lexical-binding’ is t." (quote taken from the actual documentation for `defvar`). Perhaps the advice in `Warning Tips` was written before the introduction of lexical binding in Emacs Lisp...

Comment: Not to mention `defvar` doesn't silence free variable warnings, unless you don't assign the initial value, so there's that.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The official way to do what you want is `(defvar foo-state)`.  Note the absence of a second argument.  Note also that such a declaration only applies to the file where it is found (or to the scope in which it is found, if it's used inside a function).

Comment: Thanks. Re-reading the documentation of `defvar` makes it clear: "if INITVALUE is missing, SYMBOL's value is not set." I had missed this and always provided a second argument (which caused the variable to always be bound).

Answer (score 40):

Declare the variable with `defvar`.  There is no other way to remove the warning, and it is really considered good practice.

Your intention to keep the symbol table uncluttered is worthy, but you are not actually doing so.  I think you have misunderstood the semantics of variable bindings in Emacs Lisp, since you seem to believe that by not declaring it `foo-state` will be unbound in any buffer not using `foo-mode`.  *That is not the case*.

In Emacs Lisp names (aka symbols) are *global*.  As soon as `foo-state` is evaluated the first time, the runtime creates a new symbol object for `foo-state` and puts this into the global symbol table (aka `obarray`).  There are no local symbol tables, so it does not matter where `foo-state` is evaluated and how, `foo-state` refers to the *same* symbol object at *any place* (see [Creating Symbols](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html)).

Each symbol object consists of components (aka cells), one of which is the *variable* cell (see [Symbol components](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html)).  `setq` modifies the current binding of the system, on top-level without lexical binding this effectively changes the variable cell of the symbol object, thus the *global* value of the variable.  Again, it does not matter where `setq` is evaluated.  Actually if some `bar-mode` evaluated `(setq foo-state "bar")`, `foo-state` would be bound to "bar" in `foo-mode` too, and vice versa.

Thus the only effect of `(defvar)` over `(setq)` it that *documents* the intention of using a symbol as global variable, so telling others to not modify this variable unless manipulation of the behavior of `foo-mode` is intended.  You can attach documentation to the variable, and mark as being defined in your buffer (`C-h v foo-state` will provide a link to jump to the definition).

Since Emacs Lisp lacks namespaces and is – by default – dynamically scoped, documentation is fundamentally important to avoid conflicts between modules.  If I wrote a `bar-mode` using your `foo-mode` I might accidentally bind to `foo-state`, call `foo-change-state` and then see my mode misbehaving because a variable was unintentionally overwritten.  Declaring `foo-state` doesn't make this impossible, but it at least allows me to catch the error, because `C-h v foo-state` will reveal that this variable is used by another mode, so I'd better not use it unless I really intend to manipulate that mode.

As a last word:  In all of the aforementioned text “mode” can be replaced with Emacs Lisp files.  `modes` are nothing special with regards to symbols.  All of the above also holds for Emacs Lisp that do not declare modes, but just contain a bunch of functions.

Comment: It is not true that `foo-state` will not be unbound in other buffers — just try the poster's example. While the obarray is global, values of buffer-local symbols are changed on each buffer switch, which can include a change to unbound state. If you press `M-: foo-state RET` in a `foo-mode` buffer, you will get `"bar"`, while if you do the same in another buffer, you get an error. While this is not idiomatic in elisp, it can certainly be obtained regardless of the global symbol table.

Comment: Also note that, since Emacs Lisp lacks a module system, it's not the documentation that protects you from accidental clashes of global variables, but the convention of using symbol prefixes. This is why each mode prefixes all of its symbols with `mode-`. `defvar` merely allows the compiler to emit (more precisely, *not* to emit) the warning that catches misspelled assignments, the same warning that is a false positive in the poster's case.

Comment: If `foo-state` is set by another buffer *before* `foo-mode` declares it buffer local, it gets a global value.  Only after the variable is declared buffer local, buffer-local bindings come into effect.  And even then the global binding can still be changed via `setq-default`, though this will of course not affect buffer local bindings.

Comment: Symbol prefixes help to avoid conflicts, but do not prevent them, the more since especially variables declared by programming modes often have ubiquitous names simply because the the symbol prefix (i.e. the programming language's name) is ubiquitous.  For instance, `ruby-mode`  may declare a `ruby-executable` variable for buffer evaluation through a ruby interpreter, but any other library that deals with Ruby (i.e. a flymake checker for Ruby) might also easily use this variable, because it's just the most natural name to choose for this.  That's why documentation is also needed…

Comment: So in short, does it mean that in elisp, everything is just "global variables"? Modifying one place would result in all following executions to use the new value? Very nice explanation!