# What does byte-compile-disable-warning do?

Tags: emacs, elisp

It doesn't seem to do anything at all, no matter what the argument is. It also doesn't affect the byte-compile warnings in any way. If used according to its description. Is there any example of how to use it?

For example, the code below:

```
(defmacro deflocal (var &rest body)
  (let ((symb var)
        (val (car body))
        (doc (cadr body)))
    `(progn
       (let ((byte-compile-warnings nil))
       ;; (byte-compile-disable-warning 'make-local)
       (set (make-local-variable ',symb) ,val)
       (put ',symb 'variable-documentation ,doc)
       ;; (byte-compile-enable-warning 'make-local)
       ))))
```

Can do whatever it wants to `byte-compile-warnings`, and it doesn't affect the compiler's output in any way (I still get warnings about assignment to free variable.

**EDIT:**

Because this was opaque in my description above. Here's why I don't want to use `defvar`. I have an interactive function that will start sort of interactive shell for communicating with a program outside Emacs. This shell may be started directly by user, indirectly when entering several different major modes or when performing some other tasks, like compiling, checking syntax and so on. The system is fairly complex.

I've encountered many times that certain functions may eventually set variables in the buffers I don't want. For example, when compilation hook calls a function that assumes it is called in the buffer that owns the connection object. The connection can fail, and so the system is made to try to automatically restore the connection, once it discovers that it failed for any reason (unfortunately, the other program I have to connect to is very unstable and its communication facilities are poorly implemented). So if, for example, flymake process suddenly realizes it needs to restore the connection it will create it in whatever buffer flymake was at that point. Similarly, compilation mode buffer, completion buffer, help buffers and so on. It is *very* difficult to follow after these changes of context.

Now, when I can be sure that no other buffer will accidentally declare the variable to reference the connection object, or else it will error, I'm safe, and it is easy to debug and troubleshoot the problems as they appear. However, once I use `defvar`, after a while I realize that some rouge duplicated processes have been created, and I've absolutely no clue who did that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, `byte-compile-warnings` does not do what you want.  Instead you probably want to either declare your variable with a `(defvar <VAR>)` somewhere, or wrap the code that triggers a warning in a `with-no-warnings`.

The let-binding of `byte-compile-warnings` in your code will be applied when the code is run, not when it is compiled.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a simple test to get convinced that using `defvar` with only one argument will not bind the variable everywhere, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12434028/1225607):

```lisp
(defvar foo)
(boundp 'foo) ;; -> nil

(defvar bar t)
(boundp 'bar) ;; -> t
```

Comment: I think using `defvar` without a second argument could be an option in your case: it will not create or initialize any variable, but only tell Emacs that you want to use this symbol as a variable. See for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432093/get-rid-of-reference-to-free-variable-byte-compilation-warnings).

Comment: No, it actually will not be bound if you don't specify a second argument. This is what I hadn't understood in the question linked above, until @Stephan proved me wrong. I edited the answer to provide an example; hopefully you'll see it when it is peer-reviewed.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `byte-compile-warnings` is best used as a file local
variable to control the warnings that are output during batch
compiling.

It sounds like you're concerned with the side effects of using
`defvar` but it only creates a global variable that is dynamically
bound (unless the variable is already locally bound).

After creating the local variable you can use `make-local-variable`
from within a function to make the variable buffer local for the
*current buffer* but remain global for all other buffers.  So if you
only call `make-local-variable` once there will only be two copies of
the variable, one dynamically bound and shared with all buffers, and
another that is specific to a single buffer.
*emphasized text*
    (make-local-variable VARIABLE)

```
Make VARIABLE have a separate value in the current buffer.
Other buffers will continue to share a common default value.
```

If you'd like to ensure that there isn't ever a global version of the
variable you should look into
[lexical binding](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicBindingVsLexicalBinding).

Finally, to just quiet the warnings when batch compiling this `.el`
file place the following code at the bottom of the file:

```
;; Local Variables:
;; byte-compile-warnings: (not free-vars)
;; End:
```

Comment: I edited my answer to include using `byte-compile-warnings` properly
in an `.el` file.

Comment: Maybe you can trick it using an `eval-when-compile`, possibly using a
`defvar` in there.  I'm not 100% sure but that might define the
variable as global but only while the file is being compiled.