# defvar without INITVALUE

Tags: emacs, elisp

The first tip in [Warning Tips - GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Warning-Tips.html#Warning-Tips):

> Try to avoid compiler warnings about undefined free variables, by adding dummy defvar definitions for these variables, like this:
>             (defvar foo)
>   Such a definition has no effect except to tell the compiler not to warn about uses of the variable foo in this file.

What is a scenario where someone would want no effect and yet want to disable the warning about the free variable? Whenever I got warnings about undefined free variables, it was always the case that either I forgot to put `(defvar foo initvalue docstring)` or I misspelled a local variable name.

Comment: Just put the empty `defvar` below the (require 'foo). `defvar` will not change
the value, unless it's the first one. Very similar to C/C++ declarations.

Comment: See here for a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12432093/1225607

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is why/when to suppress such warnings.  The answer is: in either of these situations:

- The variable is defined elsewhere, and you know that the library defining it will be loaded before the code actually tries to use the variable.
- You want to declare that the variable is a "special" variable, that is, it is to be bound dynamically, not lexically.