# elisp warning "reference to free variable"

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am wandering how to get rid of the elisp warning.
my setup is the following:

I have init.el file which sets "emacs-root" variable:

```
;; root of all emacs-related stuff
(defvar emacs-root
   (if (or (eq system-type 'cygwin)
      (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
      (eq system-type 'linux)
      (eq system-type 'darwin))
        "~/.emacs.d/"    "z:/.emacs.d/"
     "Path to where EMACS configuration root is."))
```

then in my init.el I have

```
;; load plugins with el-get
(require 'el-get-settings)
```

in el-get-settings.el I am loading packages with el-get and appending "el-get/el-get" folder to the load-path:

```
 ;; add el-get to the load path, and install it if it doesn't exist
 (add-to-list 'load-path (concat emacs-root "el-get/el-get"))
```

the problem is that I have a lips warning on 'emacs-root' 
in last expression for add-to-list : "reference to free variable 'emacs-root'"

what am I doing wrong here and is there any way to make the compiler happy?

this setup works ok btw - I don't have any issues during load time, just this annoying warning.

Regards, Roman

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get rid of "reference to free variable" byte-compilation warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432093/get-rid-of-reference-to-free-variable-byte-compilation-warnings)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are compiling the file where you reference the variable `emacs-root`, the variable must be already defined.
The easiest way to avoid the warning is to add

```
(eval-when-compile (defvar emacs-root)) ; defined in ~/.init.el
```

in `el-get-settings.el` before the offending form.

Alternatively, you can move the `defvar` from `init.el` to `el-get-settings.el`.

Note that you can use `eval-when-compile` in `defvar` to speed-up loading the compiled file (of course, if you do that, you should not copy the compiled file between platforms):

```
(defvar emacs-root
  (eval-when-compile
    (if (or (eq system-type 'cygwin)
            (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
            (eq system-type 'linux)
            (eq system-type 'darwin))
        "~/.emacs.d/"
        "z:/.emacs.d/"))
  "Path to where EMACS configuration root is.")
```

Note also that your original `defvar emacs-root` in the question if broken, it sets the variable `emacs-root` to `"Path to where EMACS configuration root is."` on windows.

Comment: That suggested `eval-when-compile` inside the defvar would be a bad idea if the .elc files are copied between platforms.

Comment: thank you for spotting description string in the wrong place. I am actually not even trying to compile the lisp here - the warning is coming from Flycheck which, I suppose, does compilation to detect errors. I can't move emacs-root from init.el as it is the entry point to my config which sets root and this root is used in few places. But adding (eval-when-compile (defvar emacs-root)) in el-get-sesttings.el worked! This is great suggestion, thank you!

Comment: Evaluation of `(defvar foo)` is a no-op.  So `(eval-when-compile (defvar foo))` should be a no-op, since as the name implies it should simply evaluate `(defvar foo)` during compilation.  IOW **don't** wrap `(defvar foo)` inside `eval-when-compile` since it defeats its purpose.  Of course, in reality it does work, for hysterical raisins, and also because so many people use this broken form that we're forced to make it work.

Comment: `(or (eq x 'a) (eq x 'b) ...)` is better written `(memq x '(a b ...))`.

Comment: @Stefan: `(defvar foo)` is a noop because ELisp uses dynamic bindings by default. it is not noop if the file is compiled with lexical bindings.

Comment: @sds: indeed, `(defvar foo)` is not 100% a no-op in a lexical-binding file, but it has limited scope: if a `load` a file that contains nothing but `(defvar foo)`, this will be a no-op.  But even when it's not a no-op, you shouldn't wrap it inside an `eval-when-compile` since it's mostly a compilation directive rather than something whose return value or side-effects are wanted.

Comment: @Stefan: so, you are saying that `defvar` has a compile-time effect in ELisp, like in CL. Fine. Please document it and add a warning on `(eval-when-compile (defvar ...))`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `defvar` has (and always has had) a compile-time effect.  AFAIK, `(eval-when-compile (defvar foo))` has never been necessary and even less useful.