# "malformed function" warning and require "Cannot open load file:" error

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am getting these two issues :

In toplevel form:
init.el:28:1:Warning: `(add-path (p) (add-to-list (quote load-path) (concat
    emacs-root p)))' is a malformed function
init.el:42:1:Error: Cannot open load file: exec-path-from-shell

during compiling the following elisp:

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))
;; root of all emacs-related stuff
(eval-when-compile
  (defvar emacs-root
    (if (or (eq system-type 'cygwin)
          (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
          (eq system-type 'linux)
          (eq system-type 'darwin))
      "~/.emacs.d/"    "z:/.emacs.d/")
  "Path to where EMACS configuration root is."))

 (eval-when-compile
   (defvar emacs-root "~/.emacs.d"
    "Path to where EMACS configuration root is."))

;; path to where plugins are kept
(defvar plugin-path (concat emacs-root "el-get")
   "*Path to el-get plugins.")

;; for portability with < 24.3 EMACS
(unless (fboundp 'cl-labels) (fset 'cl-labels 'labels))

;; add paths to various configuration modes
(cl-labels
  ((add-path (p)
            (add-to-list 'load-path
                         (concat emacs-root p))))
 (add-path  ".")
 (add-path  "settings")
 (add-path  "site-lisp")
 (add-path  "erlang")
 (add-path  "exec-path-from-shell"))
;; set PATH, because we don't load .bashrc
(require 'exec-path-from-shell) ;; <- Error: Cannot open load file: exec-path-from-shell
```

both these issues are very puzzling to me.

1. I don't see why this fund considered "malformed"
   `(add-path (p) (add-to-list (quote load-path) (concat
   emacs-root p)))'
2. and secondly why "require" is not able to load file.

these issues only happen during compilation, not compiled code works ok

would really appreciate any pointers

Regards, Roman

Comment: If you want to use `cl-labels` then you probably want to ensure that variable `lexical-binding` is non-`nil`.  See the doc string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have "cl-lib" loaded at compile time:

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl-lib))
```

Also, as Stefan explained in his comments in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898244/elisp-warning-reference-to-free-variable/), you should not define variables in `eval-when-compile`. Just use `defvar`.

Comment: but I do load (eval-when-compile (require 'cl)) - first line in my lisp listing. Using defvar without eval-when-compile doesn't seem to make a diff. The first (require statement always results in Cannot open load file:

Comment: the repo for this emacs setup lives here: https://github.com/RomanShestakov/.emacs.d

Answer (score 0):

`cl-labels` is provided by `cl-lib`, not by `cl`.  So you need `(require 'cl-lib)` (which you can also wrap in `eval-when-compile`).